# How to assert that constructor throws exception using CppUnitTestFramework

Tags: c++, unit-testing

Looking to verify that the constructor throws exceptions in the required places using CppUnitTestFramework.

```
Assert::ExpectException<std::exception>(Service pService = Service(hServiceManager, L"NotValidName"));
```

The above code doesn't work but I can't figure out how this should be implemented. Also can't seem to only expect specific exceptions:

```
Assert::ExpectException<ERROR_INVALID_SERVICENAME>(Service pService = Service(hServiceManager, L"NotValidName"));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Solution": Move to GTest if using Visual Studio